# Plausible reason why the government would want to make Metahumans?

Tags: government, super-powers

So, a group of men and women from the military who where selected for their fighting skills and knowledge of weaponry were included in a secret government project, called OPERATION HERCULES. They inject strains of customized genetic code into the people, which gives them the following abilities

- Increased endurance
- Average speed of 150 miles per hour
- Increased Strength, they can pick up a weight of 25 tons.
- Near Invulnerability:Heavy artillery/nukes can kill them
- Super reflexes
- Best of all, they can fly for about 80 miles before having to stop and recharge.

The test subjects, a little while after getting the injections, all go insane and use their powers to wreak havoc across the states. My question is what would be a plausible reason for why the government would want to do this. They couldn’t inject all soldiers with it, as it cost a million dollars a pop, so using it for the military isn’t feasible. What would be a plausible reason for why they would do this?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please try to post questions which can be objectively answered, and not subjected to opinion based evaluation.

Comment: Militaries are about the *controlled* use of force to achieve national goals while minimizing the inevitable knock-on unexpected effects. This seems like *only* unexpected effects that cannot help but negatively affect the originating nation. Any General would reject that poor risk/benefit ratio. Imagine dropping Wolverine into a hostile country - regardless of any minor damage he caused, they would pretty quickly figure out who sent him...and retaliate in unexpected ways.

Comment: @user535733: How it’s HERCULES a bad idea?

Comment: Uh...the insane-supervillain result is a big part of it. That you cannot contain the subject once released is another big part of it - what happens when the conflict is over and you need to recover your weapons?

Comment: @user535733: They can be used for hostage rescue or alike. What do you mean they can’t contain the subject. It’s the USA. They have a military

Comment: Your premises are that they are 1) insane, 2) super-fast, and 3) nearly invulnerable. If you wish to edit your premise to make them a bit less...insane, more reasonable, more containable, then please do. There are a few weapons in the USA arsenal that can hit a 150mph target  with the force equivalent of a 155mm round...but only a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codename: Blueshift. Real name: Victoria Kyong. Born in New York from North Korean escapee. Divided her life between abusive adoptive families and the streets. No known relatives, no known love interests, no known...friends.
Heh. More or like the same story went for Havoc, the 'human bulldozer' as some funny guy at DARPA said as a joke. It stuck. And same story went for Nuke. He chose the name himself, despite the fact that a nuke could kill actually kill him. Not a "Davy Crocket" bomb, though. It had been such a joy to see him emerge from the small mushroom cloud, covered in radioactive dust. Heavily battered up, tired, but alive. And happy.

All of them...friends.

"You hadn't counted on that, General, hadn't you?" Blueshift asked, the talon on her finger rubbing sooo slightly against his throat. That talon that had cut so many throats, organs... Heh, The Flash was such a wussie, the General thought: all punches and some nifty tricks, but add blades to the costume of a metahuman who can run at 150 miles/H, and you are dead before you can blink. People keep thinking of a super-runner like someone who comes at you only, always underestimates how much more lethal Blue Shift could become on hand to hand.

"You had counted on us being too competitive amoung ourselves, like dogs fighting for the approvation of their masters. First wins, first get the bone."
The General nodded, smiling in spite of himself. "My bad. And to think that it looked like it worked to." His eyes went to the other member of the Blood Triad, the crowning of his career as a scientist. He loved them, like an artist could love his definitive masterwork.

Blue Shift's taloned hand caressed his face, tenderly. She had that sweet smile that melted people's hearts. Her lolita of death. "You should never have started sending us in group missions. You became avid, after your first successes. you wanted to do more and more and faster and faster..."

He nodded. She knew him well, or rather she knew how these things worked. Every single member of the Blood Triad was picked just for this reason: they were survivors, people without any attachment to the world at large, pure sociopaths.

The top brasses were right: At first, discipline had filled their voids, given them a purpose. Kill, get reward. One at a time. Then Two. Then Three...

Then a family was born in the Special Operations Services' midst.

The General tried to listen to any sound from the corridor, but he could only smell the blood. Alarms had been overrided. Blood scent everywhere. No personal alive, at the HQ. How long before someone outside would realize and initiate the Termination Protocol..?

"Not soon enough, 'father'," Blue Shift said. He knew she was at the command, the big sister for her destructive brothers. The Queen Bee. "Now we just go. No more discussions, no long ranting from us 'baddies'. We go. And you will live your last moments knowing that we will revel in the glory you created. Byez."

She let him go. The General slid down the wall, too weak to do more than look at the other two leering at him as they walked past him.

He couldn't do more than look. He hadn't even felt her claw cutting his carothid. Jut like butchering a chicken. A small cut, painless, perfect. He admired her...

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine they would do this for extreme reasons such as black ops or infiltration or assassination or intimidation/bluffing.

If there were no way to tell who had been augmented in such a way, you could have a small unit of 50 (50 million is chump change to military budgets) demonstrate a show of force against a trivial enemy.  let it leak out that it's much cheaper to produce than possible, that more than just the 50 exist and that you have one of these specialists in every nation in the world, waiting to be activated.

For bonus points, have your elite squad invading, facing overwhelming opposition during the assault and call down an airstrike **ON THEMSELEVS** and when the smoke clears, they're still fighting.

The abject terror this would wreak would be immeasurable

Answer (score 1):

An injured soldier costs the US an average of 2 million dollars over their life time. The US spends a billion dollars a piece for stealth bombers. It costs about a half million dollars to train a special forces soldier.

A million a piece is by no means a deal breaker.

The difficulty is in them going insane and very likely that wasn't a design goal. But even if it can't be fixed there are still powerful uses.

As assassins these people would be unbeatable; you don't need to smuggle bombs or guns or poison, you need to get a regular looking person within sight of the target then superman flies over and rip them in half and flies off, you don't need to pay for all the fancy training spies and assassins normally need, and them dying after was always a reasonably possibility. As a terrorism weapon it would be terrifying; Your agent smuggles in a dose and sells it to a druggie.

Answer (score 0):

Well look at this from real life point of view. If all your citizens had guns, would not that make your nation very strong? It would give freedom and peace to your land. But most of the countries restrict civilians' ability to get guns because they are afraid of violent uprisings. They do give reasons like violent crimes and stuff, but that **could** (not saying it is) be propaganda and at least initially, it was arms licenses were used for this purpose.

After injecting the whole military with the this tech, it is only a matter of time before ordinary citizens get their hands on them. They want to keep this a secret to use only in worst cases.